# Check list empty

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components

With this code I trie to verify this condition , before insert I should verify that the list that it have the same recordid is empty , if it is empty I can insert else make it empty and insert .

```
@AuraEnabled(Cacheable=false)
public static Boolean insertFieldSynchro(sObject NContra , id recordId) {
    List<NContra__c>contraList = [Select id , Name from NContra__c where recordNContra__c =: recordId];
    if(contraList.size() == 0)
        insert NContra;{
    } else {
        contraList  = 0
    }
    insert NContra;
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to delete the previous record? Your code effectively just does an insert and that's it.

Comment: you could find this answer on Salesforce documentation https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_dml_examples_delete.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per as I understand you want to check if record exist based on certain condition then make that field blank and insert and if not simply insert the record.

```
    @AuraEnabled(Cacheable=false)
    public static Boolean insertFieldSynchro(sObject NContra , id recordId) {
        List<NContra__c> contraList = [SELECT id , Name 
                                       FROM NContra__c 
                                       WHERE recordNContra__c =: recordId];
        if(contraList.isEmpty()) {
            insert NContra;
        } else {                 
            NContra__c.recordNContra__c = null;
            insert NContra;
        }                    
        return true;
    }
```

You can also achieve same thing without query if your only purpose is to make that field blank

```
 @AuraEnabled(Cacheable=false)
 public static Boolean insertFieldSynchro(sObject NContra , id recordId) {
        NContra__c.recordNContra__c = null;
        insert NContra;
        return true;
        }
```

Comment: I used your code except that I changed `NContra__c.recordNContra__c = null;` by ` delete contraList `